# JQuery Cookie Plugin issue - undefined is not function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-cookie

I am trying to use the `JQuery` `Cookie` plugin, below is my code that is giving me trouble.

```
jQuery("#orderBtn").click(function(event){
        jQuery(".order-alert").show();
        event.preventDefault();
        var productArray = {};   

        //Add item to array
        if (jQuery.cookie('quote_products_cookie') === undefined) {
            jQuery.cookie('quote_products_cookie', JSON.stringify(productArray), { expires: 1, path: '/' });
        } else {
            productArray = JSON.parse(jQuery.cookie('quote_products_cookie'));
        }

        jQuery('#order_counter').html(Object.size(productArray));
    });
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It is saying the issue is on this line:

```
if (jQuery.cookie('quote_products_cookie') === undefined)
```

I don't know why it is giving me this error as I have included the script in my `header`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Can anyone shed any light on the issue?

Comment: For some reason, your jquery.cookie.js is not being included. Do you see it with the browser tools?

Comment: Just checked my source and yep, it is being included straight after the `JQuery` include.

Comment: What is the output of get_template_directory_uri()?

Comment: `http://cmpmushrooms.tld/wp-content/themes/shrooms_v0.1/js/jquery.cookie.js
`

Comment: If that's the output, then your URL is wrong. Unless you meant the output is ONLY `http://cmpmushrooms.tld/wp-content/themes/shrooms_v0.1` with no trailing `/` and no file name

Comment: `http://cmpmushrooms.tld/wp-content/themes/shrooms_v0.1/js/jquery.cookie.js` === 404

Comment: It will show a 404 because I am working on a `Virtual Host`, if I follow the link it brings me to the `cookie.js` script

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem guys, Basically I was working on some Wordpress that a colleague had done in the past and included a lot of plugins throughout the code.

Anyways, long story short, there was another version of `jQuery` being included in the `body` and in order to solve the issue I removed this and brought the `cookie` include to the `footer.php` and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Doublecheck (triple & quadruple!) that the path to jquery.cookie.js is correct and that the file parses properly. Perhaps you should fetch a fresh copy of it just in case.

The error indicates that the file is not being included or executed properly. The same error can be produced by evaluating `jQuery.nonsense() === undefined`.